# Permissions issue? Why Huawei u8650 can't install this app?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play

I developed an app that needs these permissions and these hardware:

```
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.LOCATION
android.hardware.location.GPS
android.hardware.location.NETWORK
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN

android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
```

The app is now published in google play but surprisingly i can't install it from google play into my Huawei u8650 phone. The phone haves GPS, camera, autofocus, etc... Also, i can install the app from eclipse to debug it, the app works fine on this phone.

But, surprisingly google play tels that this app is not compatible with this phone.

At the Google Developer Console, i can list the phones compatibles with this app (1843), and in the list is not contained Huawei u8650.

I can't understand where is the problem. What should i change in the app or the permissions to make it compatible?

Thanks

Comment: Does taking `android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS` put it on the list? It seems like an uncessary filter. I'd say add permissions and features one by one if nobody can answer you. Also keep in mind Google Play does still have issues when you decide to be very specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see some indications on the Internet that this device lacks autofocus.

If you do not need autofocus, add the following to your manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Autofocus is [required by default when you choose the `CAMERA` permission](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), which is why you need to proactively state that you do not need it.